# How to use multiple .each statements in ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, each

I want to do something like this,

```
for topic.sections.each do |section| and topic.questions.each do |question|
    print section
    print question
end
```

I want both sections and questions simultaneously, the output will be like this:
section 1
question 1

section 2
question 2

I know what i did there is foolish, but, what is the exact way to do this or is this even possible?

Comment: What do `sections`, `questions` contains? and What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then do below with the help of [`Enumerable#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip):

```
topic.sections.zip(topic.questions) do |section,question|
    p section
    p question
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Enumerable#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip).

For example,

```
sections = ['a', 'b', 'c']
questions = ['q1', 'q2', 'q3']
sections.zip(questions) { |section, question|
  p [section, question]
}

# => ["a", "q1"]
# => ["b", "q2"]
# => ["c", "q3"]
```